# How to slice a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file converted to JavaScript object as well as a year parameter and i want to return only the relevant array with it's name and content as a JSON.

The file looks like this:

```
{
"2012":[

    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "GPA": 80
    }    

],
"2013":[

    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "GPA": 85
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "GPA": 92
    }

]
}
```

I'm using the following function to find the array and delete all recoreds with GPA<90:

```
  getExcellenceByYear: function(year) {   //get all students with GPA>=90 by year

        fake=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(file));
        keys = Object.keys(fake);
        if(fake.hasOwnProperty(year))
        {

    for(var j=fake[year].length-1; j>=0; j--) // delete all irrelevant records
    {   
        if(fake[year][j].GPA<90)
        {
            delete fake[year][j];
            fake[year]=fake[year].filter(function(x) {return x!==null});
        }
    }


}
else
return JSON.stringify({});

return JSON.stringify(fake[year]);               
}
```

But i'm returning only the records in the array when i need it's name as well, for example:

```
{
2013: [
{
   id: 2,
   firstName: "Anna",
   lastName: "Smith", 
   GPA: 92
}
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: look up javascript map functions. I think it might be better to build a new object with the ones you want instead of deleting. I saw a tutorial on map functions and this is what they do. I don't remember enough details on how it works so I can't give an example.

Comment: how do you determine relevancy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of modifying your source data, just extract the bits that pass a predicate. Here's an example using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var data = {
  "2012":[
      {
          "id": 1,
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "GPA": 80
      }    

  ],
  "2013":[
      {
          "id": 1,
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "GPA": 85
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "firstName": "Anna",
          "lastName": "Smith",
          "GPA": 92
      }
  ]
};

function getByYear(year, gpaThreshold) {
  if (!data[year]) {
    return null;
  }
  
  var obj = {},
      aboveGPAThreshold = data[year].filter(function(datum) {
        return datum.GPA >= gpaThreshold;
      });
  
  obj[year] = aboveGPAThreshold;
  
  return obj;
};

console.log(getByYear('2013', 90));
```

Comment: Nice, that's what I was about to post. I'd like to add that if OP has control over the JSON file, he should make it an array of years, rather than an object whose properties are years : it would make it possible to just filter the array rather than having to create a new object and assign it the year of interest.

Comment: OP also wants to filter by GPA so indexing by year isn't really a bad idea. You could really index by either filter criteria (GPA or year).

Comment: Sure, I mean that it would be easier to filter a `[ {year :2013, students: [...]}, { year: 2014, students: [...]}, ...]` array rather than the current object.

Comment: That means changing all other function i have already written which are based on the current JSON file format

Comment: also take into consideration that the JSON file can be very long and hard coding it would not be such a good idea.
any way to pass it from the file to an array instead of to an object?
i have changed the format of the file to:
[{
    "year":2012,
    "students": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "GPA": 80
        }    
]},
{
    "year":2013,
    "students":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "GPA": 85
        }
    ]
}
]
@Aaron

Comment: `JSON.parse()` should then return an array. What is your problem?